# Transpose lists to form object

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the most Pythonic way to convert this:

```
{'a': ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3'], 'b': ['banana1', 'banana2', 'banana3']}
```

into this?

```
[{'a': 'apple1', 'b': 'banana1'}, {'a': 'apple2', 'b': 'banana2'}, {'a': 'apple3', 'b': 'banana3'}]
```

I would prefer a solution that doesn't use array comprehensions.

This is my current approach

```
d = {
    'a': ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3'],
    'b': ['banana1', 'banana2', 'banana3']
}

r = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if len(r) <= i:
            r.append({})
        r[i][k] = v[i]
```

Comment: But the most Pythonic way would be to use a list comprehension. Why wouldn't you want to use one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
[dict(zip(d.keys(),vs)) for vs in zip(*d.values())]
```

With `d` the original dictionary.

This generates:

```
>>> [dict(zip(d.keys(),vs)) for vs in zip(*d.values())]
[{'b': 'banana1', 'a': 'apple1'}, {'b': 'banana2', 'a': 'apple2'}, {'b': 'banana3', 'a': 'apple3'}]
```

The code works as follows, it is guaranteed that - given a dictionary is not changed - `d.keys()` and `d.values()` generate the keys/values in the *same order*: so you can `dict(zip(d.keys(),d.values()))` back into the original dictionary.

Now what we do is we make a *transpose* of the `.values()` of the dictionary, by using `zip(*d.values())`. For each such "column" (of the tranpose), we zip the column with the `d.keys()` and convert that into a dictionary (with `dict(..)`), by using list comprehension, we will eventually iterate over all rows.

Mind that the **iteration stops from the moment one of the lists in the values is exhausted**.